# every Lie group admit left invariant smooth global frame

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

The claim here is Every Lie group admits a left-invariant smooth global frame.

To prove this we use the vector space isomorphism the evaluation map $\epsilon:\text{Lie}(G)\to T_eG$, which is defined as $\epsilon(X) = X_e$.Where $\text{Lie}(G)$ is the Lie algebra of all smooth left-invariant vector field on Lie group $G$.

The problem here is since we can map back the basis of $T_eG$ to basis of $\text{Lie}(G)$.Why the basis for $\text{Lie}(G)$ forms the global frame,the global frame is the set of vector field $(E^1,E^2,...,E^n)$ that for each $p\in G$. we have $(E^1_p,E^2_p,...,E^n_p)$ linear independent.

Here We only find a vector field level basis,how to show for each point the choosen vector filed at this point are linear independent?

Comment: The set $\{E^i\}$ are linearly independent since it is a basis. By definition of linearly independent of vector fields, they're certainly linearly independent pointwise.

Comment: @Si Kucing Thanks I got it,since vector field is a function from $M \to TM$ and linear independent for a function means pointwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic argument is that every point "looks the same" as the identity by left invariance, so linear independence are the identity suffices.

Let $L_g:G\to G$ be the left translation operator $L_g(h):=gh$. These are all diffeomorphisms.

Since the frame $(E_1,\dots,E_n)$ is a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$, $(E_1(e)\dots,E_n(e))$ is a (linearly independent) basis for $T_eG$. Since $E_i(g)=d_eL_gE_i(e)$, and the differential $d_eL_g:T_eG\to T_gG$ is a linear isomorphism, $(E_1(g),\dots,E_n(g))$ is linearly independent as well.

Comment: thanks, very clear statement

Comment: I suppose you denote the Lie algebra of $G$ by $\mathfrak{g}$, that is, $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathrm{Lie}(G)$. Could you explain why $(E_1(e)\dots,E_n(e))$ is a basis for the tangent space to $G$ at the identity element? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I see the trick. The thing is, the evaluation map is an isomorphism between vector spaces. This begets that $\epsilon(E_i)$'s form a basis for $T_e G$.

Comment: Thank you, Kajelad. Your proof is just brilliant.